# Automating SAS Processes through putty and VBA

Tags: vba, shell, unix, sas

I am trying to automate a few SAS processes through shell scripting having a VBA based excel UI.

Is there a way to connect to putty through vba to connect to a remote server, run a few bash command lines to copy/move files, then execute the SAS code and get the outputs to my local?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a broad question, and the answer depends on many things!  But most importantly:

- Are you talking about a server or local instance of SAS?
- What outputs - generic outputs, or outputs you are writing specifically?

In any case..  It's worth noting you can use SAS to perform your bash commands, so long as x-command is enabled, eg as follows:

```
  data _null_;
    infile "cp source dest" pipe;
    input;
    list;
  run;
```

As for running SAS from VBA, you have multiple options (running sas.exe direct, using the IOM, using the STP server).

If you have control of the SAS code, I'd suggest using SAS to run your bash commands (via example above) and streaming your outputs to the `_webout` fileref using the STP server.  This way all your VBA needs to do is call a URL within an Excel web query, and all permissions / code security etc is handled within SAS.  This approach is described [here](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/sas-as-service-easy-way-to-get-sas-into.html).